# sending input value to backend using react & axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am basically trying to allow myself to edit a field on a page, and then when I am done editing it, just hit the submit button, and it will send it to the backend, where it will update my mongodb collection. I have this (this is my whole page -- so there's no confusion)

```
 import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/TourPage.css";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/getResults")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  deleteById = (id) => {

    console.log(id)
    axios
      .post(`/deleteDoc`, {id: id} )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked")
        window.location = "/tour"
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);

  })
}

editById = (id, location, Services, cnum) => {

  console.log(id, location, Services, cnum)
  axios
    .post(`/editDoc`, {id: id, location: location, Services: Services, cnum: cnum} )
    .then(() => {
      console.log(id, " worked")
      window.location = "/tour"
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the errors here
      console.log(error);

})
}
  render() {
    // You can handle the loader part here with isLoading flag. In this case No data found will be shown initially and then the actual data
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <table id="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>siteLocation</th>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>cnum</th>
        </tr>
        {myData.length > 0
          ? myData.map(({ location, Services, cnum, _id }, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder={location} /> </td>
                <td>{Services}</td>
                <td>{cnum}</td>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.deleteById(_id)}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.editById(_id, location, Services, cnum)}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Submit Edit
                </button>
              </tr>
            ))
          : "No Data Found"}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

as you an see, in the section where I am making the request to `/editDoc`, I am trying to pass the edited parameter of `<td><input type="text" placeholder={location} /> </td>` to the top level function `editById`. the updated paramater is not being sent. I am new to react, so please bear with me. but thanks for the help all! :)

Comment: You're not updating the state when type into your input field, you should use `onInput` event on your input fields and update the state while you're typing.

Comment: do I need it within a form then? Could you show me ?

Answer (score 0):

semantics really matters, why do you use a table if you can use a form.

look, I found couple of things

first when you click the button you need to prevent the default

- `e.preventDefault()`
- `when you send data to the backend you need to send an Stringified JSON.`
- `set the content-type to application/json`

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/TourPage.css";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/getResults")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  deleteById = (id) => {

    console.log(id)
    axios
      .post(`/deleteDoc`, {id: id} )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked")
        window.location = "/tour"
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);

  })
}

editById = (id, location, Services, cnum) => {

  console.log(id, location, Services, cnum)
  axios
    .post(`/editDoc`, JSON.stringify({id: id, location: location, Services: Services, cnum: cnum}),{
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "Application/json"
      }
    } )
    .then(() => {
      console.log(id, " worked")
      window.location = "/tour"
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the errors here
      console.log(error);

})
}
  render() {
    // You can handle the loader part here with isLoading flag. In this case No data found will be shown initially and then the actual data
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <table id="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>siteLocation</th>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>cnum</th>
        </tr>
        {myData.length > 0
          ? myData.map(({ location, Services, cnum, _id }, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder={location} /> </td>
                <td>{Services}</td>
                <td>{cnum}</td>
                <button
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    this.deleteById(_id);
                  }}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.editById(_id, location, Services, cnum)}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Submit Edit
                </button>
              </tr>
            ))
          : "No Data Found"}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying, but it didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not updating the state when you type into the input fields, so when you send the request to `/editDoc` you're sending the old data.

You need to listen to the `onInput` event on your input fields like so:

```
return (
    <table id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th>siteLocation</th>
            <th>Services</th>
            <th>cnum</th>
        </tr>
        {myData.length > 0
            ? myData.map(({ location, Services, cnum, _id }, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td><input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={location}
                        onInput={(e) => this.setState(prevState => ({
                            ...prevState,
                            myData: [
                                ...prevState.myData,
                                [index]: {
                                    ...prevStep.myData[index],
                                    location: e.target.value
                                }
                            ]
                        }))}
                    /></td>
                    <td>{Services}</td>
                    <td>{cnum}</td>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => this.deleteById(_id)}
                        disabled={isLoading}
                    >
                        Delete
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => this.editById(_id, this.state.myData[index].location, Services, cnum)}
                        disabled={isLoading}
                    >
                        Submit Edit
                    </button>
                </tr>
            ))
            : "No Data Found"}
    </table>
);
```

***Note: this is not tested, but it should work***

Comment: @developerg1000 sorry about that, I forgot to update the parameters for `this.editById` method. I just updated my answer, try again.